# android- setAdapter on AlertDialog not working

Tags: java, android, handler, android-alertdialog, listadapter

I am making a list of the user's tumblr blogs in a pop-box. All of this happens within a Handler. Here is the code:

```
private class PicHandler extends Handler{
    Context c;
    String name;
    JumblrClient client;
    public PicHandler(Context context, String n, JumblrClient cl){
        c=context;
        name = n;
        client = cl;
    }
    public void handleMessage(Message msg)
    {
        final String[] cs = preferences.getString("allBlogs", "").split(",");
        for (String s : cs){
            Log.d("DrawLog", s); //logs the blogs correctly
        }

        ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_selectable_list_item, cs);
        Log.d("DrawLog", (String) adapter.getItem(0)); //logs the first blog correctlys
        new AlertDialog.Builder(c)
        .setTitle("Choose blog")
        .setMessage("Choose the blog to publish the .gif")
        .setAdapter(adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        String root_sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
                        File file = new File( root_sd + "/Flippy/" + name) ;  
                        if(file.exists()){
                            Log.d("DrawLog", "file exists"); //file exists
                            Log.d("DrawLog", file.getPath());
                        }

                        PhotoPost post;
                        try {
                            post = client.newPost(cs[which], PhotoPost.class); 
                            //Photo p = new Photo();

                            post.setData(file);
                            Log.d("DrawLog" , post.toString()+"");

                            post.save();
                        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        catch(NullPointerException e){
                            Log.d("DrawLog", "null pointer wtf");
                        }

                   }
                }).create().show();         
        }
}
```

All the logs log the right things... It's just when the alert displays there is no list. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can either use `setMessage()` or `setAdapter()`. They are mutually exclusive. If you use both, the message wins. A solution would be to remove `setMessage()` and use `setTitle()` instead.

Comment: Aaaaahhh!! I wasted so much time because of this!! Thank you!